# Add Relation / Association model value to Base model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have two objects, `A` and `B`. Each have many of the other, using `relationshipA`. `relationshipA` has a property `propertyA`. Can I merge the properties of `relationshipA` and either `A` or `B` when I perform a fetch?

For example

```
A.find(params[:id]).relationshipAs
```

I'd like that to return me `Bs`, but also append the properties from `relationshipA` into them, at least when rendering the json.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :relationship_a
  has_many :b, through: :relationship_a

end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :relationship_a
  has_many :a, through: :relationship_a

end

class RelationshipA < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :A
    belongs_to :B

end
```

Assuming B has properties `prop1`, `prop2` and `prop3` and `RelationshipA` has `prop4`, I'd like to get a json response from:

```
render json: A.find(params[:id]).bs
```

I'd like to expect:

```
[{
    'prop1' : 'value',
    'prop2' : 'value',
    'prop3' : 'value',
    'prop4' : 'value'
}, ...]
```

Here's a console example:

```
a1 = A.create
b1 = B.create
b2 = B.create
a1.bs = [b1, b2]
RelationshipA.where(a_id: a1.id).first.prop4 = 'Hello'
RelationshipA.where(a_id: a1.id).last.prop4 = 'There'
*now output all of a1's bs including the relationships' prop4 value*
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<B id: 1, prop1: nil, prop2: nil, prop3: nil, created_at: "2014-07-09 20:37:12", updated_at: "2014-07-09 20:37:12", prop4: 'Hello'>, #<B id: 2, prop1: nil, prop2: nil, prop3: nil, created_at: "2014-07-09 20:37:12", updated_at: "2014-07-09 20:37:12", prop4: 'There'>]>
```

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly I think you need to query `A` based on the `id` but then add `includes(:b)` to the call so that all of the `B`s are included. So `A.includes(:b).find(params[:id])`

Comment: @CWitty I need to be able to find an `A` based on an id. Then I need to get all of the `B`s associated with that `A` using `RelationshipA`. However, that will only return an array of `B`s, but I need an array of hashes with both `B` and `RelationshipA`s values.

Comment: Checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations it might help. The suggestion I recommended should include both A objects and B objects of A.

Comment: Also in your console example I think you should still need to call a1.save after a1.bs = [b1, b2]

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 questions:

1. How do I generate custom json
2. How do I bring back objects to generate the custom json?

Defining a custom json method:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships, :inverse_of :a
  has_many :bs, :through => :relationships
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  # prop1
  has_many :relationships, :inverse_of :b
  has_many :as, :through => :relationships
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  # prop4
  belongs_to :a, inverse_of: :relationships
  belongs_to :b, inverse_of: :relationships
  def as_json(options: {})
    {
      prop1: b.prop1,
      prop4: prop4
    }
  end
end

relationships = A.includes(relationships: :b).find(params[:id]).relationships
puts relationships.to_json
```

The question is very abstract. If you can stick with `Relationship` objects, then that is probably your best bet. Using `includes` will give you a single or 2 queries.

If you need to have a `B` with the knowledge of how you brought back `B`, then you probably want to add `attr_accessor :prop4` to `B` and an "extension" block to `Relationship`'s `has_many` clause to set B's `:prop4`.

Comment: I've updated my question with a console example. Hopefully it can help clarify. I tried both of your examples and neither helped.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the best that I can do is a hash of the values, but not through the initial query or any built in functions. @kbrock has a solid answer, but I prefer the `attributes` approach.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships, :inverse_of :a
  has_many :bs, :through => :relationships

  # returns array of hashes, not json string, of all Relationship's and B's attributes
  def relationshipValues
    # get all of a's relationships, including `b`s with only 2 queries
    relationships = Relationship.includes(:b).where(a_id: :id).all
    relationshipValues = []
    # I'm not sure if this is optimal, so please offer some advice
    @relationships.each do |relationship|
        relationshipValues << relationship.attributes.merge(relationship.b.attributes)
    end
    # simple return - is there better way?
    relationshipValues
  #just for spacing :)
  end

end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships, :inverse_of :b
  has_many :as, :through => :relationships
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a, inverse_of: :relationships
  belongs_to :b, inverse_of: :relationships

  def to_json
    attributes.merge(b.attributes)
  end
end
```